# Mongo's Time-To-Live (TTL) index does not work for me

Tags: mongodb

MongoDb 2.0.7. 
That is how date is declared for stored object MyObject in c#:

```
public class MyObject
{
    [BsonDateTimeOptions(Kind = DateTimeKind.Local)]
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

That is how index is created:

```
Collection.EnsureIndex(new IndexKeysBuilder<MyObject>().Ascending(l => l.Created), IndexOptions.SetName("CreatedDateIndex").SetTimeToLive(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 60)));
```

`MongoVUE` tool confirms that index named `CreatedDateIndex` is created for collection `MyObject` with `expireAfterSeconds = 60`. There no more indexes declared for the `Created` field.

However items in the collection are never auto-removed, I can see several days old items still here like this document:

```
{
  "_id" : new BinData(3, "OVdRaIodPUKz7cCuaxnFpA=="),
  "Created" : ISODate("2014-01-09T23:41:08.732Z"),
}
```

What might be wrong? I can only guess that something wrong is type of data, may be it's not of Bson Date type and it even does not warn me, anyway I do not even know how can I verify it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TTL indexes are new since 2.2, while you are using 2.0.7 ...